# Version control for both Vagrant config and themes being developed

Tags: wordpress, git, vagrant

I have set up a local Wordpress development environment using [Chassis](https://github.com/Chassis/Chassis) (based on Vagrant), this needed a bit of tweaking to get it how I like, so I feel like I should have this under version control. There will be changes in future.

I will be using this Wordpress install for theme development, ideally I would like to develop in the "themes" folder, but would it cause problems having a Git repo within another Git repo?

What is the best way to manage this?

Comment: git repo in a git repo won't necessarily cause problems however what I do in this situation (using docker configs) is have a private repo for my configs and add the public themes via a `git-submodule`.

Comment: @WilliamPatton Can you develop code in a submodule? Or is it just for managing dependencies?

Comment: You can't develop directly inside a submodule sadly. I misunderstood exactly what your question was. It shouldn't cause you much trouble to work with a repo inside a repo - providing you use something like .gitignore to exclude the directories that include your themes. Presumably you will not be versioning WP within the config repo so that may already be ignored by the rules that ignore WP.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. The configuration on Chassis is held separately from WP. Themes/plugins are subfolders to the config folder.

Comment: Glad I could help you out :) If this answers the question I'll post it as an answer in a moment so that it can help others who have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific situation a parent repo would only contain configurations - and use `.gitignore` to exclude the WordPress application completely, which is where the child repo would be located, so there would be no issues having a repo-in-repo.

Both repos would be able to be developed independently and the child repo would not interfere with the history of the parent.

Comment: I have just tested this and it works well. As a bonus, learning about sub modules helped me fix another issue I came across this evening - thank you!

Comment: It's awesome to hear that you were able to get a good solution that fits in with your workflow setup from our discussion. Also happy to hear that you self solved something this evening that might have had you scratching your head this time last week :)